# VB to PHP Curl posting xml

Tags: php, vb.net, curl

I am trying to convert this VB script to PHP curl

```
xmlServerHttp.open "POST","url",False xmlServerHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
xmlServerHttp.send "xmlmessage=" & Server.URLEncode(xmlDocument)
‘ xmlDocument = the Xml Document contain the actual request
xmlServerStatus = xmlServerHttp.status

if xmlServerStatus = "200" then
xmlServerResponse = xmlServerHttp.responseText
Else
Response.Appendtolog ".xmlServer status is " & xmlServerStatus
end if
```

This is what I have so far however it is failing

```
$curl = curl_init(url);

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded') ,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xmldoc,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options );

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

// Getting results
echo curl_exec($curl);
```

The API i am calling return that the xmlmessage variable is not a valid xml document.

Comment: i think there is problem with your $xmldoc variable

Comment: convert  $xmlDoc to $xmlDoc->asXML() and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change $xmlDoc to $xmlDoc->asXML()

like this

```
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded') ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('xmlmessage='=> $xmlDoc),
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);
```

Comment: This is my xml string $xmldoc = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DemandRequest>
<UserId></UserId>
<Reference>2</Reference>
<Description>Axxess Purchase</Description>
<Amount>19.00</Amount>
<m_1>35</m_1>
<m_2>3239477</m_2>
<m_3></m_3>
<m_4></m_4>
<m_5></m_5>
<m_6></m_6>
<m_7></m_7>
<m_8></m_8>
<m_9></m_9>
<m_10></m_10>
</DemandRequest>';

Comment: the use like this CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('xmlmessage='=> $xmlDoc),

Comment: Unfortunately the result that is getting sent to me is still a failure. Do you have any other suggestions

Comment: @Jed no idea other than that.

Comment: enocde the xml data and try to send it through 'get' method

Comment: All I can think is its something on the receiving end that is broken thanks for the help